# Update case class with another one

Tags: scala

I have case class with lot of fields like:

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String, login: String, passwordHash: String, ...)
```

Also I have web page (Play) to edit some fields of `Person`. This page operates with another case class that contains subset of `Person` fields displayed on the page:

```
case class PersonProjection(id: Long, name: String)
```

There is a lot of such Projections and some fields (like `id`) can be used in many projections

Could you please suggest how I can build `PersonProjection` from `Person` and update existing `Person` instance with `PersonProjection`?

Sure I implement this transformations by myself but maybe there is some kind of best practice for this situation? Some library or pattern? Are lenses suitable here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to define `Person` in terms of `PersonProjection`:

```
case class Person(proj: PersonProjection, passwordHash: String ...)
```

Then either access the id as `person.proj.id` etc., or else add helper methods to `Person` to access these more conveniently:

```
case class Person(proj: PersonProjection, passwordHash: String) {
  val id = proj.id
  val name = proj.name
}
```

Updating from the projection is then as simple as calling copy on the `Person` instance:

```
val updated = person.copy(proj = projFromForm)
```

Comment: This will not works because I have man projections with intersected properties. I have update the question

Comment: @1esha Hmm, you could try picking the most suitable projection(s) to use to construct Person, and live with some boilerplate for the others.

Answer (score 0):

Since the field mapping is arbitrary, you can't escape having a mapping from a class to its projection. Now, going from class to projection should be pretty simple, but, in the absence of default values, going the other way around is probably more complex. Do you intend to search a backing store for some kind of ID, to retrieve the original object and then perform the update on the other fields?

If anything can help you, it will be Shapeless with its isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, I plan to retrieve full `Person` by id and apply changes from `PersonProjection`